# iCalendar .ics - how does iPhone CAL App detect changes?

Tags: iphone, icalendar

our sports website is offering our sport match events as ICALENDAR .ics file.

When opening the file's URL with iPhone's Safari the user is able to open in the iPhone's "Calendar" app.
When opening it the user is then able to add the events to the calendar.

So far so good.

But sometimes the match dates are changed.
That's why we provide a unique for that event in our system and also supply the sequence number and the last-modified timestamp.

But the iPhone's "Calendar" app is NOT detecting the change...
What do I have to provide in the VEVENT record so that the Calendar app is noticing "oh, this event has changed, I'll import it again"?

Example: this is the initial record provided to the Calendar app, event takes place on 06-Jun-2012 17:00:00

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120601T170000
DURATION:PT2H0M0S
SUMMARY:1st division match: Blau vs Rot
UID:uniqueid4711@ourdomain.de
SEQUENCE:1
CREATED:20111027T111000
LAST-MODIFIED:20111027T111000
CATEGORIES:Sports event
END:VEVENT
```

Days later the event is moved to 06-Jun-2012 19:00:
(UID is still the same, DTSTART, SEQUENCE and LAST-MODIFIED were changed)

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120601T190000
DURATION:PT2H0M0S
SUMMARY:1st division match: Blau vs Rot
UID:uniqueid4711@ourdomain.de
SEQUENCE:2
CREATED:20111027T111000
LAST-MODIFIED:20111030T170000
CATEGORIES:Sports event
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: I just see that the first item must be
    SEQUENCE:0
and the second
    SEQUENCE:1
but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try changing the UID of the modified event. This should do the trick.